# Parse.com - How to manage user login by myself?

Tags: php, android, parse-platform

I'm writing an app(run on web and Android) for my company's staffs and I want to use Parse.com to store data.

But I'would like to use my company MYSQL database to check if my staffs account and password is correct.

If I have a php file on my server, 
for example something like:

```
<?php
$account=$_POST['account'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];

if (checkifpwiscorrect($account,$pw)==true) { 
   //how can the user also log in to Parse
} else {
   // account or password wrong
}
?>
```

How to log in to Parse if account and password is correct?

Answer (score 0):

here is an login function which actually use the restClient class request method.

```
public function login($username, $password) {
        if (!empty($username) || !empty($password)) {
            $request = $this->request(array(
                'method' => 'GET',
                'requestUrl' => 'login',
                'data' => array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password
                )
            ));
            return $request;
        } else {
            $this->throwError('username and password field are required for the login method');
        }
    }
```